# Asynchronous function with for loop exit

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous

i am doing my first project. I created async function to add hover class for each element of my swiper one by one in infinite loop. I want execute function when mouse pointer is around my swiper and when pointer is on swiper i want to function to be stopped can anybody help me ?

```
const delay = async (ms = 1000) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function swiping(exit) {
    for(let i=0; i < img.length; i++){
        img[i].classList.add('imghover');
        button[i].classList.add('btnhover');
        console.log(i);
        await delay(3000);
        img[i].classList.remove('imghover');
        button[i].classList.remove('btnhover');
        await delay(400);
        if(i === 1 || i ===3 ){
            swiper.slideNext();
            await delay(300)
        }
        if(i === 3){
            i = -1
        }


    }      
}
```

Comment: Use event listeners. Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to detect when the mouse is hovering, and `click` for clicking.

Comment: Yea i know but still cannot stop this loop

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use `setInterval()` to run a function periodically. When you want it to stop, call `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with the fact that a function that returns a promise is already an `async` function, so that creating an `async` function that returns a *Promise* is fully unnecessary and has a double tick gotcha ...

```js
// first hint
const delay = (ms = 1000) =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Now, meet [AbortSignal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) which is a primitive to stop asynchronous tasks, as well as listeners and so on ... and while it's true that *Promise* doesn't accept abort signals, it's relatively trivial to implement one.

```js
function Disposable(callback, {signal}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    signal.addEventListener('abort', reject);
    callback(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

So now we have a way to abort previous promises but keep in mind these will throw / reject when that happens, so you need to handle that, but to demo that code:

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
new Disposable(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'OK');
  },
  controller
)
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

// abort the promise before it resolves
setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 500);
```

This means that now you have a way to abort delays:

```js
const delay = (ms = 1000, controller) =>
  new Disposable(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms), controller);
```

so that now you can use either a shared `AbortController` to stop all delays or you can create one per each `delay` and pass its signal along.

Comment: to whom it might concern, I've published [a tiny module](https://github.com/WebReflection/promise#readme) that offers abortable and resolvable promises via the `AbortSignal` standard approach.